# Vuforia 6.5 in Unity 2017 Camera open

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am using Vuforia 6.5 in Unity2017.2, but everytime I play my scene my camera opens up. Although I have deleted all files of vuforia, but after playing a new folder comes up "Resources" and in that I see "VuforiaConfiguration. I have attached the screenshot.

[image: After Playing Main Camera got Vuforia Scripts]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why it is enabling vuforia on scene play. My camera gets on everytime.

Comment: The plugins is still likely in one of the folders. Close Unity, go to your project directory and delete every plugin file. That should solve your issue

Comment: @Programmer Not working. I have tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem , I intentionally added Vuforia Behaviour on Main Camera and disabled it, i.e Uncheck it. Below is the screenshot. This trick will not enable ARCamera on that Scene.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Unity go to `File -> Build Settings -> Player Settings (make sure Android is selected) -> XR Settings` then uncheck the *Vuforia Augmented Reality Supported*. Save and restart Unity.

Comment: I have started the project again, I just want one scene to be AR, rest are simple but using new Vuforia and latest unity 2017, camera gets enabled on all the screen. Need help.

Comment: @vanshika What do you mean camera gets enabled? How do you add a camera to the scene?

Comment: I have added only MainCamera, but it Vuforia Augmented Reality Supported is enabled on every scene, I see Camera (facetime Camera, if app is working on Mac OS) in place of normal maincamera.

Comment: @vanshika Then just remove the Vuforia components from the main camera